# OneSignal отправить уведомление через php

Tags: php, cordova

Этот код отправляет на устройство c идентификатором ids пуш уведомление.

Как создается player_id и откуда брать все это ? чтобы отправлять нужному пользователю не писав каждый раз его player_id

```
<?PHP
    function sendMessage(){
        $content = array(
            "en" => 'English Message'
            );

        $fields = array(
            'app_id' => "5eb8а37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
            'include_player_ids' => array("6392g91a-b206-4b7b-a620-cd68e32c3a76","76ece62b-bcfe-468c-8a78-839aeaa8c5fa","8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86"),
            'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
            'contents' => $content
        );

        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        print("\nJSON sent:\n");
        print($fields);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                                   'Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }

    $response = sendMessage();
    $return["allresponses"] = $response;
    $return = json_encode( $return);

    print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
    print($return);
    print("\n");
?>
```

Comment: Распишите конкретнее что не так.
[Откуда берутся id](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/reference#view-devices)

Comment: player_id берутся из OneSignal , как они создаются и где я сам незнаю, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: В коде приведенном выше, у Вас уже забиты 3 айдишника и всегда сообщения будет отправляться им.
Как получить id девайсов, смотрите по ссылке в сообщение выше, стандартный апи OneSignal.
`"https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players?app_id=" . $app_id`  где `$app_id` id вашего приложения